# Apache2 shows default page when I visit the site without 'www' on an android device, but works fine with 'www'

Tags: django, web, apache2, linode, django-3.0

I deployed Django website: [www.alahaberry.com](http://www.alahaberry.com) on Linode Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Whenever I try to access it with my computer, it works just fine whether I add www or not. Today my friend tried to check it out from his android device and the apache2 default page appeared. This only happened on android device (or maybe all mobile). I tried with BlueStacks too the same. Without www it shows default apache2 page. Please what could be wrong. I really need your help. Thanks advance.
I used letsencrypt to get SSL on it. My alahaberry-le-ssl.conf looks like this:

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port th>        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName      
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to   
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this 
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.  
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.      

        ServerName alahaberry.com
        ServerAlias www.alahaberry.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,   
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the   
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only        
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


        Alias /static /home/admin/alahaberry/static
        <Directory /home/admin/alahaberry/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/admin/alahaberry/media
        <Directory /home/admin/alahaberry/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/admin/alahaberry/alahaberry>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/admin/alahaberry/alahaberry/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess alahaberry_app python-path=/home/admin/alahaberry pyth>        WSGIProcessGroup alahaberry_app


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.alahaberry.com/fullchain.pem        
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.alahaberry.com/privkey.pem       
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The issue happens when you access your site over http and without www, I don't think it has anything to do with Android

Comment: Please do you know how to solve the problem?